# SumDigits using Parameter

Tags: java

Okay, so I created a DigitsSum application. The class is DigitsSum and it does contain a static method called sumDigits(I AM DONE WITH THIS). ( However I didn't get this part) The names must match these including the capitalization, the sumDigits method should take a single parameter, an integer, and return the sum of the digits in that integer, sumDigits method should not print anything, and it should return its answer using a return statement. I can use a main method to test my sumDigits method, and all printing should happen there. I would like to know whether if i did perfectly fine or no..also method return should be like if entered a number, suppose 345, then output should be 3+4+5=12 --> 1+2 = 3. what i am doing wrong here? Thanks in advanced!

```
  import java.util.Scanner;


     public class SumDigits {

            public static double sumDigits (int a){
                int sum;
                int t= a%10;
                sum= t+t;
                a = a/10;
                return (sum);   
            }

            public static void main (String [] args){

                double sumDigit;    
                int integer;

                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");   
                integer = in.nextInt();

                sumDigit = sumDigits(integer);
                System.out.println ("The sum of the digit is:" +sumDigit);

            }
        }
```

Comment: you need recursive method for `sumDigits`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you're missing a few things:

- You should always close streams and any external resource in general. *id est*: closing your `Scanner` before leaving your `main` method
- As it has been pointed out in the comments, you should use a recursive method to implement `sumDigits`, because it reflects the actual behavior you're trying to implement.

Your code could be like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static int sumDigits(final int a) {
        int sum = 0;
        int b = a;
        do {
            sum += b % 10;
            b = b / 10;
        } while (b > 0);

        if (sum >= 10) {
            return sumDigits(sum);
        }

        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        double sumDigit;
        int integer;

        try (final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
            integer = in.nextInt();

            sumDigit = sumDigits(integer);
            System.out.println("The sum of the digit is: " + sumDigit);
        }

    }
}
```

What I did here in the recursive method can be decomposed in two parts:

1. You calculate the sum of all the digits of the given number (done by the `do/while` loop)
2. If that sum itself is greater or equals to 10, then we need to return the recursive application of `sumDigits` on that value... otherwise, just return `sum`.

Note that I didn't only change the `sumDigits` method but also the `main` one, so it closes the `Scanner` using the [try-with-resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax.